# What's the meaning of "should we be interested"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, expressions

I contacted someone and he replied:

> ...
>
> I've passed your information along and someone will get back to you **should we be interested**.

After sending him another message he replied:

> ...
>
> ... will return **should we be interested**.

Is this a question?

> I've passed your information along and someone will get back to you. **Should we be interested?**.

What do I have to reply? What's the meaning of this expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a conditional phrase. You might think of it as being the same as

> ...if we are interested

So your original sentence means:

> I've given your information to other people, and **if we are interested**,
>   someone will contact you.

Comment: Yes; don't confuse the 'should we be interested' = 'if we decide we are interested' usage with the 'should we be interested?' = 'ought we to be interested?' usage. Auxiliaries, perhaps especially modals, have confusingly different usages.

Comment: +1 But it also means *We are not (yet) interested, but if things change, we will get back to you.*

Answer (score 2):

It means ***if*** we're interested.